# What regular expression would I use to find the word "oy"?

Tags: javascript, regex

What is regular expression would I use to find the word "oy"? I need it to work in a userscript. Also, I have to make sure it doesn't remove words that contain "oy", like "Olive Oyl".

Comment: `(?<=.*)(O|o)(I|i|y|Y)` Will this suffice? It catches `Oy` or `oy` or `Oi` or `oi`. Hope it helps

Comment: @Drknezz You need a `(\smate)?` at the end :)

Comment: @alex O: Dont know what those options are... :p

Comment: @Drknezz It's an Australian thing :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need `/\boy\b/g`.

**Explanation:**

The `\b` means word boundary (start or end of a word). The `g` on the end means to search for more than one occurence (global). Finally, if you want the search to be case insensitive, add an `i` after the `g`:

```
/\boy\b/gi
```

To remove all "oy" words in a string `str`, you do:

```
str.replace(/\boy\b/gi, "");
```

Comment: +1 for getting it 30 seconds earlier (*and*, an explanation) :)

Comment: 27 seconds earlier actually ;-)

Comment: @rockinthesixstring, actually 33" ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
/\boy\b/g
```

Will be the literal regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest trying `/\boy... Oh nevermind.`

It *is* a bit hard to find questions easy enough to solve that haven't already been answered to death, right? Right?

Comment: Thanks for that :P `'hello oyaBC Oh nevermind!'.match(/\boy... Oh nevermind./)`